# Wordpress: Using svg as header image

Tags: wordpress, svg, header

I am using wordpress, theme Twenty Fourteen. I would like to add a svg image as header. I have no problems with uploading svg images (I use them already successfully on my webpage), but when I try to use it as head image the following message occurs: "There has been an error cropping your image". Does anybody knows what the problem is?

Thank you!
Best wishes,
pradhana

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Its the GD Library not installed.

Just use this command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

Use this to stop Apache for it to make changes

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Start Apache now and everything is fixed.

```
sudo apachectl start
```

Comment: I think this looks like an answer I saw out on the WordPress support forums.  But I am working out on some sandbox that this book, "WordPress Explained" pointed me to.  It's called Jurassic.Ninja.  I do get a dashboard with User Info to log back in, SSH User and password, SSH command, SFTP Connection String, and Server Path.  But I don't know where I would go to type in this sudo command especially on this free sandbox.  This is not my normal environment.  I'm an ASP.Net guy on windows.

Answer (score 0):

As Shubham007 said, the GD Library is not installed.

However, for PHP7 on CentOS or EC2 Linux AMI:

```
sudo yum install php70-gd
```